# Android Kotlin Dynamic column and row listing without creating a model each table?

Tags: android, kotlin, rows

We have many report View tables on the MSSQL database and new report View tables are constantly being added. I created the API endpoint to pull the data from these tables with their names, **such as: /report/:reportname** 
When I enter the table name in the report section of the link, it lists all the data in the table as JSON.
**The numbers of columns in tables are not equal.rows and columns dimanic**. How do I list data without creating individual models for each table?

Is there a library that lists data without writing a Model ?

class ReportModel {

```
@SerializedName("data")
var data: List<DataEntity>? = null
@SerializedName("report")
var report: Boolean = false

class DataEntity {
    @SerializedName("FILTRE")
    var FILTRE: String? = null
    @SerializedName("FILTRETIPI")
    var FILTRETIPI: String? = null
    @SerializedName("ACIKLAMA")
    var ACIKLAMA: String? = null
    @SerializedName("VIEW_ADI")
    var VIEW_ADI: String? = null
    @SerializedName("RAPOR_ADI")
    var RAPOR_ADI: String? = null
    @SerializedName("RAPOR_ID")
    var RAPOR_ID: String? = null

}
```

}

I want models to be generated automatically according to the data from the endpoint API

how can I solve this problem ?